# JQuery change the value of an <img src="" by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some simple JQuery code so I can change the src value of a specific img.

It's currently:

```
<img id="myImage" src="image1.gif" />
```

and I need to change it to:

```
<img id="myImage" src="image2.gif" />
```

using JQuery.

Comment: Wow, 5 identical answders in under 2 mins...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using: `$(function(){ ... });`

You can use:

```
$('#id').attr('src', 'newImage.jpg');
```

to change the image source immediately.

---

Alternatively, you can use jQuery animations to change an image.

**JS**

```
$("#id1").fadeOut();
$("#id2").delay(200).fadeIn();
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img id='id1' src='one.jpg'>
    <img id='id2' src='two.jpg'>
</div>
```

(Don't forget to change the CSS of `#id2` and put `display: none` as initial state).

Comment: your fadein/fadeout example is useless without explaining how to use CSS positioning to _make sure the images are in the same place_!

Comment: Don't need to place them for this basic example (the hidden one will let the place to the second one). Btw this is just an example. I won't give all the CSS doc here.

Answer (score 12):

That's elementary, use jQuery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)...

```
$('img#myImage').attr('src', 'image2.gif');
```

Comment: no, _don't_ qualify the `#id` tag, it prevents use of the fastest `getElementById()` DOM call.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set attributes on given DOM element:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myImage').attr('src', 'image2.gif');
});
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: I think, its the best answer among all. Think twice before downvote

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#myImage').attr('src','theothersrc.gif')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#myImage").attr('src', 'image2.gif')
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("myImage").src = "image1.gif";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).