# Recover user information with a username recover input in AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking to retrieve a user's avatar using their user name, retrieve it in an input field. However what I did does not work and I am not familiar with Ajax. Could someone help me and explain the procedure to me?

```html
<input type="text" name="username" class="input" placeholder="Your username">
<img id="#result" src=""></img>
```

Here is my ajax

```js
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "App/Actions/PlayerGetFigure.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            login: function () {
                return $(':input[name="username"]').val();
            },
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my PHP

```php
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Models\UsersManager as Users;

$Users = new Users();

$username = $_POST['username'];

if (isset($username)) {
    $user = $Users->getByUsername($username);
    if ($user) {
        echo $user['avatar'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: I have just understood the why of the how. I pass a $_POST method I must pass a $_GET method to be able to retrieve the information from my input field.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Does the AJAX work correctly? One issue is that [`<img>` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) have a ["nothing" content model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-content-nothing) and can't hold any content; if `$user['avatar']` is an image URL, you may want to assign it to the `<img>` element's [`src` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/src) instead of its value. See [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/).

Comment: Finally I would like to recover the url of the image stored in the database and assign it to the element `<img>` when I mark the nickname of a person.

I had a PHP error is that it could not find `$ _POST['username']` because I did not validate my form. I just had to pass my "username" value through a `$_GET` method

Comment: `$_POST` should work, since your AJAX request is set to `type: "post"`. See [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): "*type*: An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0." However, you're accessing `$_POST['username']` when the value is posted under the "login" key: `data: { login:`. To see the posted values, you might try `echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";`.

Comment: Okay, I just understood. However now I have another problem. I recover my image well in ajax but I can't change the source of my image when a user writes his nickname

Comment: Is the value of `$user['avatar']` an image URL? That's what I was saying earlier about [setting the `<img>` src attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery).

Comment: Oh ok ! But how can I change the value of my <img> with the response I receive in Ajax?

Comment: By assigning the value to the `<img>` element's src attribute. Also see [JQuery change the value of an <img src=“” by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046487/jquery-change-the-value-of-an-img-src-by-id/9046502). E.g. `$('#result').attr('src',data);`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work with my code :
`success: function (data) {
            $('#result').attr('src', data+'.jpg'); 
            console.log(data);
        }`

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data);`? Does it include the ".jpg" part already?

Comment: I have the data I expected, the url of my image.

Comment: Does it change the image `src` to something like `avatar.jpg.jpg`? Does it include the correct path to the image (e.g. `images/avatar.jpg`)?

Comment: Yes, insert the image is correct, it's my #result element which does not update the source of my image that I assign to it in the "success" function

Comment: Ah, the HTML says `id="#result"`. It should likely say `id="result"` (no hashtag). [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m2e31scg/).

Comment: Ok I'm definitely stupid. thank you very much for your help, Everything works, my god, it was horrible but I can understand everything thanks to you
 !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210701/discussion-between-benjamin-peuple-and-showdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally take this approach, it looks a bit cleaner for me (assuming that `$user['avatar']` returns the path to the image)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="username" class="input" placeholder="Your username" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    let username = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "App/Actions/PlayerGetFigure.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { login:username },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Models\UsersManager as Users;

$Users = new Users();

$username = $_POST['username'];

if (isset($username)) {
    $user = $Users->getByUsername($username);
    if ($user) {
        $avatar = $user['avatar'];
        echo "<img src='$avatar'></img>";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="input" placeholder="Your username">
<img id="result" src=""></img>
```

I would advise the following jQuery.

```
$(function(){
  function getAvatar(username){
    var url = "";
    $.post("App/Actions/PlayerGetFigure.php", { login: username }, function(data){
      url = data;
    });
    return url;
  }
  $("input[type='username']").change(function(){
    $("#result").attr("src", getAvatar($(this).val()));
  });
});
```

This assumes that the PHP Script will return a (Relative or Absolute) URL Path to the Image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! In fact I expected a response with the `$_GET` method because my goal was to update as soon as my input field is filled. So I went through a `$_GET` method and I manage to recover the data I wanted (the url of a user's avatar). However I can't update the avatar with my "success" function

Comment: @BenjaminPeuple that does not make sense wince your PHP Script is set for `$_POST` variable.

Comment: Yes, I modified it, now I go through a variable `$_GET`.

Comment: And your code could not work, you pass a input type "username". But your solution helped me a lot ! I didn't know that the $.post() and $.get()  methods existed in Jquery.

Comment: @BenjaminPeuple yes, they are shorthand for `$.ajax()` for the respective method.